# Xcode not listed as CMake generator on Linux

Tags: linux, xcode, cmake

Attempting to generate an Xcode project file from a simple hello world C++ source on Ubuntu 16.04.

`$ cmake -G Xcode ..` from empty subdirectory Xcode throws an error:

`CMake Error: Could not create named generator Xcode`

I used `$ cmake --help` to check the generators, but Xcode was not listed as a generator (Unix Makefiles, Ninja, Watcom WMake, etc. are listed). Currently using `cmake version 3.8.0-rc1`. Also tried with 3.5 to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generators are only available for platforms, where the tool-chain exists. This is not specific to Xcode as Visual Studio is only provided on Windows.

The [documentation states](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html):

> CMake Generators are platform-specific so each may be available only on certain platforms.